# Installing an ExternalProject with CMake

Tags: build, cmake, installation, build-process, external-project

I have the following code in one of my `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
FIND_PACKAGE(sphinxbase)
if (${SPHINXBASE_FOUND})
    INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${SPHINXBASE_INCLUDE_DIR}/sphinxbase/)
else ()
    ExternalProject_Add(
        sphinxbase
        GIT_REPOSITORY      "https://github.com/cmusphinx/sphinxbase.git"
        GIT_TAG             "e34b1c632392276101ed16e8a05862e43f038a7c"
        SOURCE_DIR          ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/sphinxbase
        CONFIGURE_COMMAND   ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/sphinxbase/autogen.sh
        BUILD_COMMAND       ${MAKE}
        UPDATE_COMMAND      ""
        INSTALL_COMMAND     ""
        BUILD_IN_SOURCE     ON
        LOG_DOWNLOAD        ON
        LOG_UPDATE          ON
        LOG_CONFIGURE       ON
        LOG_BUILD           ON
        LOG_TEST            ON
        LOG_INSTALL         ON
    )
    ExternalProject_Get_Property(sphinxbase SOURCE_DIR)
    ExternalProject_Get_Property(sphinxbase BINARY_DIR)
    SET(SPHINXBASE_SOURCE_DIR ${SOURCE_DIR})
    SET(SPHINXBASE_BINARY_DIR ${BINARY_DIR})
    SET(SPHINXBASE_LIBRARIES ${SPHINXBASE_BINARY_DIR}/src/libsphinxbase/.libs/libsphinxbase.a)
    INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${SPHINXBASE_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
endif ()
SET(DEPENDENCIES ${DEPENDENCIES} sphinxbase)
SET(LIBS ${LIBS} ${SPHINXBASE_LIBRARIES})
```

In addition to the TARGET that I'm trying to install, how would I go about installing this ExternalProject?  Right now I'm trying to do it like this:

```
install(TARGETS ${LIBS}
        LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
        ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib
        OPTIONAL
        )

install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME}
        RUNTIME DESTINATION bin
        )
```

But I'm getting the following error thrown at me:

> ```
> CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:197 (install):
>   install TARGETS given target
>   "/Users/syb0rg/Dropbox/Development/Khronos/Khronos/lib/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/.libs/libsphinxbase.a"
>   which does not exist in this directory.
> ```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Command flow `install(TARGETS)` installs *targets*, which are created with `add_executable` or `add_library` commands. For install concrete *files*, you need to use command flow `install(FILES)`.

Instead of installing selected files from subproject's *build* directory, you may install subproject *as is*. For that you can use

```
make DESTDIR=<...> install
```

command as `INSTALL` option of `ExeternalProject_Add`. This command will install **whole subproject** into directory given as `DESTDIR` parameter for make (more information about this parameter can be found [here](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/DESTDIR.html)).

Then you may use `install(DIRECTORY)` command for install all subproject's files at once:

```
# It is better to use binary directory for download or build 3d-party project 
set(sphinxbase_SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/lib/sphinxbase)
# This will be used as DESTDIR on subproject's `make install`.
set(sphinxbase_DESTDIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/lib/sphinxbase_install)

ExternalProject_Add(
    sphinxbase
    GIT_REPOSITORY      "https://github.com/cmusphinx/sphinxbase.git"
    GIT_TAG             "e34b1c632392276101ed16e8a05862e43f038a7c"
    SOURCE_DIR          ${sphinxbase_SOURCE_DIR}
    # Specify installation prefix for configure.sh (autogen.sh).
    CONFIGURE_COMMAND   ./autogen.sh --prefix=${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}
    BUILD_COMMAND       ${MAKE}
    UPDATE_COMMAND      ""
    # Fake installation: copy installed files into DESTDIR.
    INSTALL_COMMAND     make DESTDIR=${sphinxbase_DESTDIR} install
    ...
)
# Actually install subproject.
install(
    DIRECTORY ${sphinxbase_DESTDIR}/
    DESTINATION "/"
    USE_SOURCE_PERMISSIONS # Remain permissions (rwx) for installed files
)
```

Note, that **root directory** is used as `DESTINATION`. This is because files under `sphinxbase_DESTDIR` directory already located in accordance to `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX`, which is passed as `--prefix` option to `configure.sh` (`autogen.sh` in the given case).

If you know, that subprojects installs its files only under installation prefix (given by `--prefix`), you can make main project installation more *packaging-friendly*:

```
install(
    DIRECTORY ${sphinxbase_DESTDIR}/${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/
    DESTINATION "."
    USE_SOURCE_PERMISSIONS
)
```

Because now **relative path** is used for `DESTINATION` option, the project will correctly support packaging. For example, `make DESTDIR=<...> install` will work for main project too.

---

Note, that even if `ExternalProject_Add` is used for build *CMake* subproject, targets created in this subroject are not seen by the main project.

Comment: What's the difference between the `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` + `DESTDIR` dance, versus just using `./autogen.sh --prefix=${sphinxbase_DESTDIR}/${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}` and not overriding `INSTALL_COMMAND`? For this use case, it's inconvenient that `DESTDIR` is relative to the configure prefix.

Comment: @HunterZ: In autotools, `--prefix` is not just a directory under which all needed files will be copied on `make install`: 1. In case of system-wide prefix, like `/`, `/usr/local`, `/opt`, some files may be installed **outside of the prefix**. 2. It could be absolute path stored in the one project's file for refer to the other project file. Because of (2), it is better to not use "fake" `--prefix` - it would confuse the project. As opposite `DESTDIR` is never uses inside the project's files, and there is a garantee that all project's files will be installed under given directory.

Comment: I think this answer might only work on Linux; I can see why you gave a Linux answer because the OP is clearly working with .a files, just wanted to mention this in case somebody else is looking for a Windows answer. I get the feeling that there's a more cross platform option that might work with both, but unfortunately I'm not sure what it is.

Comment: @jrh: More precisely, this is GNU Make-specific approach, which supports `DESTDIR=...` semantic. Or even autotools-specific ones. Possibly some CMake generators which works on Windows has similar semantic too. But "Linux way", "Windows way" or even "cross-platform way" ... I am very unsure they exist. "I can see why you gave a Linux answer because the OP is clearly working with .a files" - No, this is not because of `.a` but because of `autogen.sh` is used for configure the project. It is part of autotools which as far as I know works only on Linux.

Comment: This topic seems to get rather poor coverage online unfortunately; [cmake's official docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.13/module/ExternalProject.html) imply that there's a way to [`install()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.13/command/install.html#targets) the targets of an external project but there's no "project" overload of this (I'm hoping they didn't mean "install every individual built file from the external project"; other pages mention that using `-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=<INSTALL_DIR>`, and omitting INSTALL_COMMAND will work (no dice). I'd guess it's possible somehow.

Comment: a very useful answer! don't forget to add `install(DIRECTORY ... USE_SOURCE_PERMISSIONS ...)` to keep the executable permissions for binaries in that directory (if you build binaries)

Comment: @xealits: Thanks for the comment, I have added USE_SOURCE_PERMISSIONS to `install(DIRECTORY)` calls.